# How to retrieve original destination address

Tags: windows, sockets, proxy, udp, iptables

I'm using a REDIRECT iptables rule from my router(OpenWRT) to redirect certain UDP packets from the server A to the server B and I need to know how to get the original destination address(like a proxy).

I already found a lot of information on how to do this on Linux using TProxy and other methods but unfortunately I don't see how to use them on Windows, there is some alternative?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `REDIRECT` iptables target, the original destination IP address is overwritten. It is lost and cannot be recovered.

Also, iptables only runs on Linux, so your question about how to do this on Windows doesn't make sense.

Comment: As I said, the router is linux and redirect using iptables.

Comment: Yes, no no MS Windows is involved.